# Revoking permissions programmatic-ally in Android

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Is it possible to remove or revoke permission from an application in Android Marshmallow?
Note that it should be done on runtime, so using ADB shell scripts or converting app to it's byte DEX code is out of question, as architectural changes is not an option for the required solution.

Answer (score 4):

Only if your application is a system app, signed with the platform key then the answer is yes.

You can revoke and apps permission with:

```
getPackageManager().revokeRuntimePermission("com.example.application", permissionName, Process.myUserHandle());
```

Refer the source here: [PackageManager.revokeRuntimePermissions](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#3314)

It may not be accessible when you are building your app with Android SDK rather than AOSP source, use of reflection might help.

Comment: How come I don't have the .revokeRuntimePermission function? and why I don't find it anywhere in Android docs?

Comment: It is a system API, not for third party apps, hence there will not be any reference to it in the docs. You might need to access it through reflection. Refer the link to source I just added in the answer for more information.