# Is there a way to revoke Ignore Battery optimization permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I was able to make a request to Ignore battery optimization but I want to revoke this permission programmatically. So is it possible to toggle the battery optimization permission and remove the app from the whitelisting apps?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555650/revoking-permissions-programmatic-ally-in-android

Comment: I don't think this will work because it says in the documentation link attached to the answer :
`Revoke a runtime permission that was previously granted by {@link
 #grantRuntimePermission(String, String, android.os.UserHandle)}` 
and when requesting Ignore battery optimization we don't use`grantRuntimePermission`.